# How to draw with an "inverted" paint in Android Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, skia

I draw some stuff on a canvas, over I want to draw a circle in inverted color :

```
canvas.drawCircle(zx, zy, 8f, myPaint);
```

How to configure `myPaint` for circle pixel to be in the inverted color of the underlying pixels ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
float mx [] = {
             -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f 
    };
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(mx);

p.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));

canvas.drawCircle(zx, zy, 8f, p);
```

Comment: I tried with no success :( I get a black circle, whatever the under picture is.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to find other solution.

Comment: No problem. It seems like the background color is not taken into account, even when using things like setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.XOR)) or setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR))

Comment: Now I get a static white circle. Do I need to set another âraùeter? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd say a color matrix for inverting should look like this:

```
float mx [] = {
         -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  255.0f,
         0.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  255.0f,
         0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,  255.0f,
         0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f 
};
```

[Here](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/manipulate-visual-effects-with-the-colormatrixfilter-and-convolutionfilter/) is more information for the matrix: